# мультиязычная программа

Tags: c#, visual-studio, f#

есть задача сделать программу, где GUI будет реализован на c# через конструктор, а скрипт, который будет что-то рисовать в gui, на f#.

как из всего этого сделать цельную программу?

использую visual studio 19, .net fraemwork

Comment: Скомпилировать F# как DLL и подключить к C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# и F# компилируются в т.н. *.Net сборки* (корректнее будет слово "собираются"). Рантайм в ходе исполнения ничего не знает про то, на каком языке что-то раньше было написано, везде один только *байт-код*. Так что программа должна состоять из двух сборок.

Традиционно (эта традиция возникла не на пустом месте), IO обращается к логике, а не наоборот. По этому решение - просто реализовать отдельную либу на F# (в решении Visual Studio нужно создать новый проект с F#), подключить как проекту на C#, и из C# дёргать логику определённую на F#.

Comment: Кстати, у нас в проде так. Там один C#-проект, в котором определён GUI на авалонии, и пара десятков  проектов на фарше, реализующих разные участки бизнес-логики.